# Problema al editar un CRUD

Tags: php, mysql, php7

> el formulario

```
<form class=""  action="editar.php?id=' . $id'" method="post">
```

> el editar.php

```
<?php

include_once("conexion.php");

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {

 $id = $_GET['id'];

 $query = "SELECT * FROM personas WHERE id = $id";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
   $nombre = $row['nombre'];
   $apellidos = $row['apellidos'];
   $genero = $row['genero'];
   $dni = $row['DNI'];
 }
}

if(isset($_POST['editar'])) {
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
  $apellidos = $_POST["apellidos"];
  $genero = $_POST["genero"];
  $dni = $_POST["DNI"];


  $query = "UPDATE personas set nombre = '$nombre',apellidos = '$apellidos',genero = '$genero',dni = '$dni' WHERE id = '$_POST['id']')";

   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

   if(!$result) {
     die("fallo");
   }

   $_SESSION['message'] = 'Persona guardada satisfactoriamente';
   $_SESSION['message_tipo'] = 'primary';

   header("Location:index.php");
 }

?>
```

Estoy tratando de hacer un CRUD, puedo insertar pero en el momento de editar no hace nada directamente salta que falló por el `if(!$result)`.

En el formulario intenté varias cosas, ponerlo simple (editar.php) pero nada, veo en muchos videos que están con la versión vieja y se hace difícil,
si me pudieran ayudar les agradecería.

Comment: El método del formulario es POST, por tanto, deja esto así: `$id = $_POST['id'];`, luego, simplifica la consulta, ya tienes el dato en la variable `$id`, entonces úsala: `$query = "UPDATE personas set nombre = '$nombre',apellidos = '$apellidos',genero = '$genero',dni = '$dni' WHERE id = $id";`  puede que las comilas simples del uso de `$_POST` ahí provoquen un error. Fíjate que no puse comillas simples, asumiendo que la columna `id` es numérica. Por último, intenta capturar el error para ver si pasa algo a nivel de la BD: `die("fallo: {mysqli_error($conn}");` Ya nos dices...

Comment: No se si será este el error pero fíjate que en la etiqueta del formulario (que creo que imprimes desde PHP) falta un punto para concatenar correctamente la variable $id con el resto del string. En caso de que no la imprimas desde PHP, te sobrarían las comillas simples, el punto de concatenación y la variable $id debería estar entre llaves de apertura y cierre de PHP con el "echo" correspondiente.

Comment: sea GET o sea POST el error es el mismo, salta directamente al if(!result), ademas para aclarar yo no quiero editar el id, lo que quiero hacer es desde el id seleccionado poder editarlo, porque sino me edita todas las tablas(y lo intente xd)

Answer (score 1):

No me queda claro cómo se relacionan los dos bloques de código que muestras: por una parte un `SELECT` y por otra parte un `UPDATE`.

A pesar de ello, casi seguro de que el código se puede mejorar, te propongo la escritura de un código controlado que te informará de cualquier error que pueda ocurrir.

Aquí se controla:

- El estado de la conexión
- El estado de los datos pasados por POST usando una asignación basada en ternarios, con la ventaja de usar posteriormente las variables asignadas
- El estado de las consultas. Si hay errores se capturará el error (esto se puede cambiar por un mensaje personalizado en un futuro, aquí simplemente se obtiene el dato de `mysqli_error` para fines de depuración.
- Todo se recoge en un array llamado `$info`, el cual se evalúa al final para imprimir los posibles mensajes.

Intenta así, si tienes dudas, pregunta en comentarios.

```
<?php 
    include_once("conexion.php");
    if ($conn) {
        $id=!empty($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id']: NULL;
        $info=array();
        if ($id){
            $query = "SELECT * FROM personas WHERE id = $id";
            if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                   $nombre = $row['nombre'];
                   $apellidos = $row['apellidos'];
                   $genero = $row['genero'];
                   $dni = $row['DNI'];
                }else{
                    $info[]="No se encontraron filas";  
                }
            } else {
                $info[]="Error en la consulta SELECT: {mysqli_error($conn)}";
            }
        } else {
            $info[]="No se pasó el ID";
        }


        if(isset($_POST['editar'])) {
            $nombre=!empty($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre']: NULL;
            $apellidos=!empty($_POST['apellidos']) ? $_POST['apellidos']: NULL;
            $genero=!empty($_POST['genero']) ? $_POST['genero']: NULL;
            $dni=!empty($_POST['DNI']) ? $_POST['DNI']: NULL;
            if ($nombre && $apellidos && $genero && $dni) {
                $query = "UPDATE personas set nombre = '$nombre', apellidos = '$apellidos', genero = '$genero', dni = '$dni' WHERE id = $id";
                if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
                   $_SESSION['message'] = 'Persona guardada satisfactoriamente';
                   $_SESSION['message_tipo'] = 'primary';
                   header("Location:index.php");
                } else {
                    $info[]="Error en la consulta del UPDATE: {mysqli_error($conn)}";
                }
         }else {
             $info[]="Faltan datos para el UPDATE";
        }
        }else{
            $info[]="No se posteó opción de editar";
        }
    }else{
        $info[]="No hay conexion";
    }
    if ($info) {
        echo implode("\n", $info);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, funciono c: